¿como optimizar importacion de datos, laravel?
estoy importando las tablas de mi version anterior de aplicacion a una nueva, para esto cree un comando,  y en su manejador, tengo esto:
he intentado varias formas entre ellas les expogo las siguiente, recien comienzo con esto de la programacion, pero me gustaria saber si existe alguna forma e mejorar el tiempo de importacion.
public function handle()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');

    $limit = 1000;
    $offset = 0;
    $startTime = microtime(true);

    // Obtener el número total de registros para la barra de progreso
    $totalRecords = DB::connection('dbasc')->table('pagos')->count();

    // Crear una instancia de ConsoleOutput para la barra de progreso
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $totalRecords);

    // Iniciar la barra de progreso
    $progressBar->start();

    $fecha_hoy = now();

    do {
        
        // Obtener datos de la tabla antigua
        $oldData = DB::connection('dbasc')
            ->table('pagos')
            ->leftJoin('recibos', 'pagos.nrorecibo', '=', 'recibos.nrorecibo')
            ->select('pagos.*', 'recibos.id as recibo_id', 'recibos.idasociado as asociado_id')
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->get();

        if (!$oldData->isEmpty()) {
            DB::transaction(function () use ($oldData, $fecha_hoy) {

                $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO pagos_por_stand (id, stand_id, recaudo_id, recibo_id, asociado_id, positem, monto, estado, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ';
                $values = [];

                foreach ($oldData as $data) {
                    $values[] = "(
                    {$data->id}, 
                    {$data->id_stand}, 
                    {$data->idrecaudo}, 
                    " . ($data->recibo_id ?? 'NULL') . ", 
                    " . ($data->asociado_id ?? 'NULL') . ", 
                    " . ($data->positem ?? 'NULL') . ", 
                    {$data->pago}, 
                    {$data->estado}, 
                    '{$fecha_hoy}',
                    '{$fecha_hoy}'
                    )";
                    unset($data);
                }

                $insertQuery .= implode(', ', $values);
                DB::statement($insertQuery);
                
            });
            // Vaciar buffers para evitar la saturación de la memoria
            DB::statement('RESET QUERY CACHE');
         
            $offset += $limit;
           
            unset($values);
            gc_collect_cycles();
            // Avanzar la barra de progreso
            $progressBar->advance($oldData->count());
        }
    } while (!$oldData->isEmpty());

    // Finalizar la barra de progreso
    $progressBar->finish();

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
  
    // Calcular y mostrar el tiempo total de la importación
    $endTime = microtime(true);
    $totalTime = $endTime - $startTime;
    $this->info('Data imported successfully in ' . round($totalTime, 2) . ' seconds');
}

sucede que tengo uno 37.000 registros, pero demora una barabaridad, como 40 minutos. comento ademas que los primeros 10000 resgistro los hace en 22 segundo aprox y luego demora cada vez mas y mas, que prodria modificafar para optimizar esta importacion de datos.

¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de ambas tablas? Puntualmente sería bueno saber como has definido la columna nrorecibo en ambas tablas, como así también saber si creaste índices sobre las mismas.

Por otro lado, es un "problema" conocido que el utilizar OFFSET en tablas que contienen una cantidad de datos, el rendimiento se vea afectado. Pero 37k no sería la gran cosas, por lo que dudo que sea tu caso.

Como indicó Marcos, es el problema de OFFSET. Hice la selección de 1000 registros en 1000 registros, por el campo id, y todo rápido.

Pídele a Marcos que deje una respuesta para aceptarla, o acepta la tuya, si es que responde a tu pregunta.
